# Is there a way to generate differences when a server is out of sync with DSC Configuration?

Tags: dsc, powershell-v4.0

The following command can be used to determine if there has been configuration drift on a system:

```
Test-DscConfiguration –CimSession $session
```

The command only returns true or false.  Is there a way to retrieve a list of what those differences are?

Comment: As I understand it, trying to take an existing server and back-port it into a configuration-management regime is usually a difficult task. Might be easier to simply build a new environment using DSC and then migrate your apps/sites/whatever into it.

Comment: It was more about determining why a server no longer matched the DSC configuration.  Perhaps someone loaded or removed something from the server, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, not at this time.  You can run Test-DscConfiguration with the -Verbose switch and the verbose messages may tell you what is not in compliance.  You should also be able to run Get-DscConfiguration and compare the existing state to the configuration document to see what differs, but there is no nice object structure with the components out of compliance.